# Regarding probabilites for naiveBayes algo

Tags: r, probability, naive-bayes, multi-class, laplace-smoothing

I have trained my data with naiveBayes algo in e1071 package. I have 6 classes in my data. I have predicted test data. the prediction returns only one class for each data point but I would like to know the probability of all 6 classes for each data point in test set. Please help me to know how to calculate the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/e1071/docs/naivebayes), you have to set `type='raw'` within `predict`.

> -**`type`**:
>
> If "raw", the conditional a-posterior probabilities for each class
>   are returned, and the class with maximal probability else.

About the needs for Laplace smoothing (from Wikipedia Naive Bayes [paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)):

> If a given class and feature value never occur together in the
>   training data, then the frequency-based probability estimate will be
>   zero. This is problematic because it will wipe out all information in
>   the other probabilities when they are multiplied. Therefore, it is
>   often desirable to incorporate a small-sample correction, called
>   pseudocount, in all probability estimates such that no probability is
>   ever set to be exactly zero. This way of regularizing naive Bayes is
>   called Laplace smoothing.

From the Wikipedia Laplace smoothing [paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing):

> The pseudocount $\alpha > 0$ (`laplace` parameter in R function) is
>   the smoothing parameter ($\alpha = 0$ corresponds to no smoothing).
>   Some authors have argued that $\alpha$ should be 1, though in practice
>   a smaller value is typically chosen.

From the examples in the R documentation, we see that `laplace` can also be set to higher values such as 3.

Comment: After setting type="raw" I get: 

class 1: NaN
class 2: NaN
class 3: NaN
class 4: NaN
class 5: NaN
class 6: NaN

Comment: After laplace transform it's working. Can you please tell me what should be the appropriate value for parameter laplace = "?"

Comment: basically when you have unknown words in your test, set without Laplace smoothing, you get zero probabilities (see for instance http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108797/in-naive-bayes-why-bother-with-laplacian-smoothing-when-we-have-unknown-words-i). I have also edited my answer. From the documentation examples it seems that `laplace=3` works