# R: Naive Bayes model e1071, why does it works with totally different columns in training ad testing?

Tags: r, naive-bayes, sentiment-analysis, e1071

I'm working with the `e1071:: naiveBayes()` function, but I don't figure out how it works. My doubts arose when I read [this post](https://rpubs.com/cen0te/naivebayes-sentimentpolarity). I've posted this question on SO, but I think that probably it fits better here, so I deleted it from there.

It seems that the function works without checking if the column names in the testing dataset, are the same in the training dataset.

Here an example, I got two datasets (in the bottom of the post, `dput()` them) like those:

```
> trainNB
  com dot tiger jail and angry hungry birthday happy     sent
1   1   1     1    0   0     0      0        0     0 positive
2   0   0     0    1   0     0      0        0     0 negative
3   0   0     0    0   1     1      1        0     0 negative
4   0   0     0    0   0     0      0        1     1 positive
> testNB
  good spot very amazing place boring     sent
1    1    1    1       0     0      0 positive
2    0    0    0       1     1      0 positive
3    0    0    1       0     1      1 negative
```

As you can see, I'm trying sentiment analysis, I've clean up a bit the code, and I had this datasets of training and testing (respectively `trainNB`, `testNB`).

The columns are different, it means that there isn't any column with the same name in the two dataset.

So I tried the above mentioned function:

```
library(e1071)
classifier <- naiveBayes(as.factor(sent)~.,trainNB)
pred <- predict(classifier, newdata=testNB)
```

And they both works (results are nonsense I suppose)! I'm concerned because I cannot figure out how it gives any kind of result, also because, in my real data, I got 95% of accuracy (bigger dataset).

*In my real dataset some columns are in common, so I firstly thought that it selects the common ones( between train and test), as stated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383754/r-naive-bayes-and-laplace-even-turned-off-works-fine-with-unseen-words-in-test), but if so, it should not work in my example posted here.*

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119922/predict-the-class-variable-using-naivebayes) an interesting point, it seems you can predict via Bayes rule with a test dataset with only some of the columns in the training, and also if you give dimensions that are not in the training set. I do not know how.

However it seems that gives some constant probability to unknown data:

```
pred <- predict(classifier, newdata=testNB, 'raw') 
pred
     negative positive
[1,]      0.5      0.5
[2,]      0.5      0.5
[3,]      0.5      0.5
```

So the question is: why is it working, and how?

Thanks in advance.

---

Data:

```
trainNB <- structure(list(com = structure(c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, 
`4` = 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), dot = structure(c(`1` = 2L, 
`2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, `4` = 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    tiger = structure(c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, `4` = 1L
    ), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), jail = structure(c(`1` = 1L, 
    `2` = 2L, `3` = 1L, `4` = 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    and = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 2L, `4` = 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), angry = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, 
    `3` = 2L, `4` = 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    hungry = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 2L, `4` = 1L
    ), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), birthday = structure(c(`1` = 1L, 
    `2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, `4` = 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    happy = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, `4` = 2L
    ), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), sent = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("negative", "positive"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")

testNB <- structure(list(good = structure(c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 1L
), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), spot = structure(c(`1` = 2L, 
`2` = 1L, `3` = 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    very = structure(c(`1` = 2L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), amazing = structure(c(`1` = 1L, 
    `2` = 2L, `3` = 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    place = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), boring = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 1L, 
    `3` = 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), sent = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("negative", "positive"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @Peter Flom, I'm not asking a new dataset, I'm asking about this algorithm works, and why it is working when it -probably- should not. In case, if it's not clear, I'll gladly edit the question.

Comment: @Xi'an, I'm not asking a new dataset, I'm asking about this algorithm works, and why it is working when it -probably- should not. In case, if it's not clear, I'll gladly edit the question