# How to choose prior in Laplace Smoothing Naive Bayes?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

Please check the image for reference
How to choose the prior probability of each feature .

Should we use the same prior for every feature or different features use different prior.

for example `P(Color = Blue | Stolen = Yes )  = (0 + 1(1/3)) / 5 + 1`  , where I used the smoothing parameter (alpha) = 1 and p = 1/3 as color can have 3 values i.e Red Blue and Yellow. So I am a little confused here , should I consider Blue also here or should I just consider Red and Yellow

Also for the other features should I use the same `p = 1/3` or for them it should be `p=1/2` as they only have two values .

Kindly check the image [image]

Comment: Could you give us more details on what exactly were you asked to do and what exactly is the Laplace smoothing formula you are referring to? The [usual definition of Laplace smoothing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421307/variance-maybe-of-categorical-data/421316#421316) has only one parameter.

Comment: Given the Attributes that are`< Color = Blue , Type = Sports , Origin= Domestic >`, predict using Naive Bayes that whether the car can be stolen or not.

The formula for Laplace smoothing is almost the same as you provide, however in the numerator, a prior P is multiplied to the alpha.
[Here is the image for further reference](https://imgur.com/a/EKbgJDo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [more standard](https://towardsdatascience.com/laplace-smoothing-in-na%C3%AFve-bayes-algorithm-9c237a8bdece) definition of [Laplace smoothing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421307/variance-maybe-of-categorical-data/421316#421316) is defined as adding a fixed quantity $\alpha$ to each count

$$
\hat p_i = \frac{n_i+\alpha}{\sum_{j=1}^K n_j+\alpha} =  \frac{n_i+\alpha}{(\sum_{j=1}^K n_j) + K\alpha}
$$

where $\alpha$'s [can be thought as "pseudocounts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435393/could-someone-please-give-a-concrete-example-to-illustrate-the-dirichlet-distrib/435444#435444)", i.e. with $\alpha=1$ you assume that for each of the categories you observed $+1$ sample like this, with higher values leading to more smoothing and lower values to less smoothing.

Splitting $\alpha$ to the [two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314277/what-should-be-taken-as-m-in-m-estimate-of-probability-in-naive-bayes) $m$ and $P$ so $mP=\alpha$,  to me seem unnecessarily complicated. Still, if you remember that $mP$ is a "pseudocount" added to each observed count, it may be easier to grasp an intuition on what the reasonable values could be.

Comment: so K here is the no of values in that feature ?
Assume training set contains 10 positive examples, and the feature 
“Size” has 3 values, but 1 value (size=medium) is not observed in :
`4: small 
0: medium
6: large`

so K here will be 3 ?

`P(small | positive) = (4 + 1) / (10 + 3) = 0.394 
P(medium | positive) = (0 + 1) / (10 + 3) = 0.03`

Comment: @Skywalker correct, $K$ is the number of categories, so as in your example, if there are three possible sizes, $K=3$.